No module named 'distutils' but also 'requirement already satisfied:setuptools in ./.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (72.1.0)
I'm working on trying to test a new data quality tool (Soda). It requires you to have Python and Pip installed and optionally docker. What I've done so far is: install the Soda package I can use to write and check data quality rules on a database (Postgress in this case). I have Docker Desktop running to set up their prepared example data source and now I'm trying to connect to Soda using a configuration file (yaml). The step by step guide tells me to now do this:
In Terminal, return to the tab in which the virtual environment is active in the soda_sip directory. Run the following command to test Soda’s connection to the data source.
Command: soda test-connection -d adventureworks -c configuration.yml. Here soda test-connection is the tool, adventureworks is the example dataset and configuration.yml is my configuration file (to data_source as well as soda).
This command gives me an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'. Online I've seen more questions about this and the advice was to use pip install setuptools or brew install python-setuptools. I've tried both, but I keep getting the ModuleNotFound error. When I check, the module is installed: Requirement already satisfied: setpuptools in ./.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (71.1.0).
The full output:
(.venv) leonie@Leonies-MacBook-Pro soda_sip % soda test-connection -d adventureworks -c configuration.yml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leonie/Desktop/soda_sip/.venv/bin/soda", line 5, in <module>
    from soda.cli.cli import main
  File "/Users/leonie/Desktop/soda_sip/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/soda/cli/cli.py", line 38, in <module>
    from soda.scan import DEFAULT_SCAN_DEFINITION_NAME, REMOTE_SCAN_MODE, Scan
  File "/Users/leonie/Desktop/soda_sip/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/soda/scan.py", line 16, in <module>
    from soda.common.env_helper import EnvHelper
  File "/Users/leonie/Desktop/soda_sip/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/soda/common/env_helper.py", line 4, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

What can I try? I've also seen people say go back to python 3.11, but that's not a solution that will help me in the future.
Currently working on Mac (M1) Sonoma 14.5 and in an active venv.

What are you trying to do when you get that error? Please show the full command and traceback, not just the error message. For instance, if you're trying to install a package and get that, that package may need to be updated (or you can try pip install --no-isolated-build)... but that's just a wild guess that you're trying to install something.

So sorry, just updated my message with some more context!

No worries – but can you please show us the command output? IOW, from your $ soda test-connection -d adventureworks -c configuration.yml to the error. My educated crystal ball guess is that the soda utility is attempting to e.g. install a package that doesn't work correctly with Python 3.12 right now due to certain setuptools changes, and due to pip's setup isolation, the setuptools that is installed in your venv isn't visible during that package installation...

That would makes sense, I've added the full output now!

Thanks! Okay, the traceback sheds light on things. (It wasn't a nested pip installation, like I had guessed.) Can you try to be explicit and install setuptools in exactly that venv: /Users/leonie/Desktop/soda_sip/.venv/bin/python -m pip install -U setuptools?

(In the meantime, I submitted a PR that removes this dependency from soda. You weren't the only one noticing this.)

This gives me the same results sadly:
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (72.1.0)``` Similar outputs when I try the folder with python3 instead of python.

That's unfortunate and strange. Well, as a temporary patch, you can simply open /Users/leonie/Desktop/soda_sip/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/soda/common/env_helper.py in your favorite editor and patch out the offending line to be e.g. strtobool = lambda s: s == "1"...
